# Python 3.x: len(myList) not matching actual number of elements of myList

Tags: python

I have a dictionary, myDict, containing many (120k+) keys with list-values that I append to each key appropriately.

I noticed when I return myDict, some key-values with e.g. one element in the list will show `len(myDict["key_with_one_list_entry"])` > 1.

The opposite does not occur as far as I can tell.
What can be the reason for this? Could key collisions cause this?

Minimum reproducible ex:

```
fileDict = defaultdict(list)
for file in os.listdir("."):
    if file.endswith(".sh"):
        with open(file, "r") as file_ptr:
            for i, line in enumerate(file_ptr):
                if i == 0:
                    continue
                fileName = line.split("/")
                _targetId = _getFileParametersFromFileName(fileName[-1][0:-1])
                fileDict[_targetId].append(fileName[-1][0:-1])


def _getFileParametersFromFileName(fileName):

    _fileNameParameterList = fileName.split("-")
    return _fileNameParameterList[2]
```

These files are created before, there is no risk for collision as these are the only *.sh files in the directory.
There are approximately 130k keys in "fileDict" with list-values ranging from 1 to 12 entries.

Comment: What does `print(myDict["key_with_one_list_entry"])` print?

Comment: what do you have in this key ? if it is string then you get length of this string.

Comment: Any chance this is a race condition where the value changes in-between your check on the length and using the value?

Comment: lists/dicts are a core part of python... Im reasonably sure that the error is not with python, but with what you think you have vs what you actually have ... but there is not enough here to actually help you solve your issue

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Whatever the problem is, you have not provided enough information for anyone else to observe it. More likely than not, you are misconceiving what is happening.

Comment: What does `type(myDict["key_with_one_list_entry"])` return?

Comment: If you overwrote a 1-element list with a list with more than 1 element (by assigning the longer list to the key which was originally linked to the former) then of course Python will report the length of the second list since the first list is no longer linked to that key.

Comment: That's correct, the dict returns one element. There is nothing wrong.

Comment: "Reproducible" means that someone can run your code an reproduce what you see. You have *not* provided code which constructs a dictionary with the odd property that it contains as values 1-element lists which the Python `len()` functions reports to have more than 1-element. Instead, you have provided code which when run on unknown files clashes with your unstated expectations.

Comment: With your final example I get that `len(fDict['0000000000001275'])` is 1 as expected. Whether or not you can provide the files, you should be able to construct an example with the properties that you claim it has (*if* such an example is possible, which I strongly doubt).

Comment: @Kabel I'm not trying to be difficult here, but you really need to read [mcve]. Your question needs to contain the entire problem. Per the link, "Complete – Provide all parts someone else needs to reproduce your problem *in the question itself*"

Comment: As far as reproducibility goes, you can provide the complete contents of a *short* text file that reproduces the problem. If your question relies on external links, it it not really reproducible.

Comment: @Kabel if I go about downloading these data files, I still cannot reproduce your issue, since the code you have posted does not run as-is. I _want_ to figure this out for you, as do many others here, but we cannot go about doing so without a small, running example we can copy and run on our own machines. As this problem depends on some data it is not the end of the world to download some data file, but it is preferred to make the problem as small as you possibly can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I'll bite. I have reworked your code like so,

```
from glob import iglob
from collections import defaultdict

target_files = defaultdict(list)

for path in iglob('tesscurl*.sh'):
    with open(path, "r") as file:
        for i, line in enumerate(file):
            if i == 0:
                continue

            file_name = line.split("/")[-1].strip()
            target_id = file_name.split("-")[2]
            target_files[target_id].append(file_name)


def print_target(target):
    print(target, len(target_files[target]), target_files[target])


print_target('0000000000001275')
print_target('0000000000028465')
```

This outputs,

```
0000000000001275 1 ['tess2019112060037-s0011-0000000000001275-0143-s_lc.fits']
0000000000028465 1 ['tess2019112060037-s0011-0000000000028465-0143-s_lc.fits']
```

Or in short: **I cannot reproduce the issue**. Now, in the comments to another answer, you mention running this in a notebook. Are you aware that repeated runs of a single cell might erroneously update the global state, and thus cause the dictionary of targets to be updated more than once? I suspect that is the issue at hand, rather than something fundamental in Python none of us seem able to reproduce. I suggest you restart your kernel to clear the workspace, and re-run all cells just to be sure.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to Stackoverflow!

You are mistaken. Consider, Python is a twenty-year-old language, with an active development team and a huge bank of tests. Ask yourself, how likely is is that such a fundamental bug would have remained undiscovered all this time, only to reveal itself when your code comes along.

One of the more difficult aspects of learning to program is accepting that you make "avoidable" mistakes all the time. Your question assumes rather a lot, without offering any evidence.

Might I suggest that you either edit the question so that you can demonstrate what's actually going wrong, or delete it and post a new one. You may find [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) helpful in formulating your question to attract answers.

Comment: Good answer (+1) even though it is really more along the lines of a comment which is too large to fit as a comment. Most programmers encounter bugs which cause them to either doubt their sanity or the rationality of the world. Perhaps this is one of those cases for OP.

Comment: @Kabel Did you simply *print* the list which you think only has 1 element but `len()` says has more than 1? The very first comment to your question was perhaps the best, but you never responded to it. I don't think that people are "touchy", but your way of phrasing it (and the title of the question itself) at least suggests that you think that the problem lies with Python rather than your code.

Comment: @Kabel  *How* did you print the list? Was it simply `print(myDict["key_with_one_list_entry"])` or was it something like `for s in myDict["key_with_one_list_entry"]: print(s)`?

Comment: just for fun: python was started in 1989 (!) and originally released in 1991 - so it's closer to 30 years old! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Python

Comment: What does `[len(s) for s in fdict['0000000000001275']]` produce in a situation where you think that it has length 1 but Python reports length 12? The most likely explanation is that the list has 1 nonemepty string and 11 empty strings.